# Compilation project - MySql.Data, version=6.8.3.0

Tags: compilation

I have a problem with the program, when compiled and threw on another system that displays my problem running. I installed net connector, and it did not work.

Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, version = 6.8.3.0, Culture = neutral, publickey token = c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. You can not find the file specified.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRZhs.jpg

I recorded the whole process. 
http://youtu.be/kYhAiJ1BhCg

Answer (score 0):

Check if "'MySql.Data, version = 6.8.3.0, Culture = neutral, publickey token = c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies" assembly is in GAC (c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL) And if it`s not, add this assembly. I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i havent this file in this folder. I tried to create the file, but I can not. In his system, or do not have that file, and the program comes normally.le but its work normaly